# How to read pin status (high/low) in Spartan FPGA 3E

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, fpga, verilog, xilinx

For Arduino => digitalWrite(LED,digitalRead(PIN))

This one I want to make in Verilog for Spartan FPGA. I know if I bind a wire to led using ucf and change the value then led will be on/off. But how to read pin status which I can see on Spartan board.

Thank you for your time.

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module:

```
assign led = switch ;
```

map the input port/signal `switch` to the corresponding I/O pin in UCF/XDC with appropriate pull-up/pull-down if needed.

map the output port/signal `led` to the corresponding LED in UCF/XDC.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as you write to it: you define the pin mapping type (I.e. input of some electrical type), you use a constraint file (in your case, ucf) and assign a signal name to it, and you just work with that signal.